# Adding to variable through php won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, addition

I have a php script which charges a credit card for a payment system, but the thing is that I have a script with a variable in it, which I am trying to add 1 to everytime a function in the php script is called, only problem is that it doesn't work. I am not sure if there is something wrong with the code, or if it is because the variable isn't saved when a new page is loaded, because everytime the php script is called it redirects to a new page.

html script with variable called product1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                var currentBid = 1;
                document.getElementById("currentBid").innerHTML = currentBid;

                function addOne() {
                    currentBid = currentBid +1;
                    document.getElementById("currentBid").innerHTML = currentBid;
                }

            </script>
```

php script with the function called chargeCard.php

```
    <?php 

    require_once('./stripe-php/init.php');

    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("Removed for safety");

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $myAmount = $_POST['amount'];
    $describtion = $_POST['description'];

    $myAmount = round((int)$myAmount*100,0);

    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $myAmount, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $describtion));

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">addOne();</script>"';

    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // The card has been declined
    }

?>
```

The function I am trying to call in the php script is the line `echo '<script type="text/javascript">addOne();</script>"';`

Comment: hit f12 and reload the page. any errors in the console? In how far is the php-script related to the product1.html? How is your php script called?

Comment: I might think that is the problem, because it is the same script I am using to call for the chargin functions, which work but I haven't done anything to connect the script with the javascript function, can this be the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: How is the PHP coming into the page.... ? are this two files called separately ? -- in this case it will never work.

Comment: Yes they are two seperate files.

Answer (score 2):

all I can see on first sight is a syntax error:

you have a double quote too much ( " ).

could it be that ?

the corrected echo is :

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> addOne(); </script>';
```

Comment: I have just tried it, still doesn't work but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hi I think maybe the echo in php happen before the element "currentBid" is loaded in the DOM. do you get any JavaScript errors ? (f12)

Comment: No, I am testing it in EasyPHP so I don't think the javascript errors show.

Comment: Do you think it is because the amount resets when I load the page because it isn't saved?

Comment: EXACTLY,you cannot exchange variables between 2 files running one server-side and one client side separately, The script have to work as one. You need a different approach. The answer of Justin Vandehey gives you an option using the PHP session. Alternatively you can also use cookies. If I have time I will also post a solution... now I'm a bit buisy...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to carry over a JavaScript variable from one page to another. Unfortunately, once you leave the scope of the current page, JavaScript variables are wiped out.

It looks like you're already using a form to POST to the server, so what you can do to maintain the state of that data is to pass back and forth between the server and the client in your form.

For example:

In the HTML, assuming your current form is structured as below:

```
<form method="POST" action="/enterYourHandlerUrlHere">
    <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">
    <input type="text" name="amount">
    <input type="text" name="description">
    <!-- This is the important line -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currentBid" value="<?php echo $currentBid ?>">
</form>
```

In your PHP, before you render the above to the browser...

```
<?php

    $currentBid = (isset($_POST['currentBid']) ? $_POST['currentBid'] + 1 : 0);
```

When you render your HTML to the screen, your $currentBid value will be stored temporarily in the hidden input on the page, where it can be accessed locally on the client, and will be accessible for your backend logic as well for as long as you keep the chain going.

Alternatively, and likely preferably, you can simply store the variable in the $_SESSION superglobal array, as such:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['currentBid'])) {
    $_SESSION['currentBid'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['currentBid']++;
}
```

This will maintain your data across multiple web requests, as PHP has this nifty superglobal to keep track of user data. For additional information regarding configuring and using the $_SESSION variable, please visit this link for the official documentation:

[PHP: Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

The Session solution will probably be more work, but is definitely worth it!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have edited the scripts but still nothing happends. I have linked to the scripts in pastie

html:
http://pastie.org/private/nxc5n7eoxbl4l2o96zw

php:
http://pastie.org/private/x9qxp08xy1fj2m3zzn9z0q

Answer (score 1):

**Key concept:**
1.  php runs on server-side.
2.  javascript runs on client-side

**Issue:**
server do not have variable that is being set by javascript because it's being set on client-side.

**Approach:**
Your javascript needs to send the variable to server before your php is being able to process the script with the varilable from javascript.

**Method:**
Use hidden form and have this form send variable to the php script.

Perhaps this would fit your case but, generally speaking, it should.

```
<form name="hidden" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="addone" value="<script type=\"text/javascript\">addOne();</script>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

and your php code; add this line:

```
$currentbidget=$_POST['addone'];
```

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the `value="<script type="text/javascript">addOne();</script>" />` line because it isn't working, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Oops, I saw my own mistake.  I removed `echo` from `action=` as it should read as `action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` and we are supposed to escape `"` inside the javascript tag.  Edited my answer already.

Comment: I have edited the scripts, but it still won't work, I think it is because my form for "posting" to the php script is a bit different because that is how the charging works, but I have made two pasties so you can see how it looks.
php: http://pastie.org/private/lcs7fmklhhw2oaxnmixn8w
html: http://pastie.org/private/7hbef8g6f6ddgytzwhtcg

Answer (score 0):

you are having a scope issue current bid can't be changed from within function unless accessing global

Comment: Do you mean I should access the php script from the html script or vice versa?